# Right aligning image in max-width div

Tags: css, html

I have a wrapper div with a max width of 700px and the only content is an right-aligned image of less than 700px width. Since it doesn't fill it, the wrapper doesn't expand to 700px. How can I make the wrapper expand to the full width when there is space in the browser window? The only hack I have found so far is to also include a zero height span with more than one line of text in...

Comment: I would assume this would work just like that, can you show us the code?

Comment: Oooops, I failed to add display:block to the image style. Once that was added, the max-width div expanded properly.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

A div should by default expand horizontally to the width of it's parent object. Try setting a width on the div to 700px.

Comment: Then the divs won't resize for a smaller browser window. I need:
1. div width expands to 700px when browser window is > 700px
2. div resizes when browser window size is reduced

It's fine if there is lots of text content as the div expands to fit it all in, but if there is just an image or a short line of text then the div shrinks to the content size.

Answer (score 1):

As CRasco mentioned, a Div will normally expand to fill its container, until we come along with some fancy style and screw that up. Here are the styles I can think of off the top of my head that will prevent a Div from expanding to fill its container:

These will make it the smallest size needed to hold its contents.

- `float: left;`
- `float: right;`
- `display: inline;`
- `display: inline-block;`

And, of course, any of these would set or restrict the size of the Div. I'm betting you'd have noticed if these were causing your problem, but I thought I should include them to be as complete as possible.

- `width: 100px;`
- `max-width: 100px;`
- `height: 100px;`
- `max-height: 100px;`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow: hidden` on the 700px div, assuming that you are not setting an explicit height.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the with of the image you could add a margin to it.